# Gradle settings for this project are not configured yet - android studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm trying to load an existing project and i'm running into these problems:

[image]

clicking ok i will have this:

[image]

[image]

Searching [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) I have not found grangle 2.2.2. Minimum grandle is 3.0.0

**build.grandle**:

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app.build.grande**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.prouast.heartbeat"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

// add a task that calls regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // relative path to jni source
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=../jniLibs',
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            'all',
            'NDK_DEBUG=1'
}

task ndkClean(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // relative path to jni source
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=../jniLibs',
            'clean'
}

// add this task as a dependency of Java compilation
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(['ndkBuild'])
}

clean.dependsOn(['ndkClean'])

sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    //jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile project(':libraries:opencv')
}
```

Need I to change something on app grandle or anybody have some suggestion?
Could you suggest me some links to follow or explain step by step how can I solve it?

##### EDIT

:
adding the jcenter to gradle.build resolves the issue:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: reimport your project. Steps: Close the project> Click on Open Project(don't use open recent)> Select project from the path

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Ok for gradle wrapper or go manually at build.gradle and update the following line :

```
    **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'**
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click OK for Studio to automatically perform the Gradle configuration.